# Using parameters for stored procedures on MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL or T-SQL for the following example:

Write a PL/SQL or T-SQL procedure to retrieve and output the marina number, slip number, rental fee, boat name, and owner number for every slip whose length is equal to the length stored in `I_LENGTH`.

**So far I've come up with this:**

> 'Create Procedure Boat_Info (I_Length IN Marina_Slip.Length%Type) AS 
>   I_Marina_Num   Marina_Slip.Marina_Num%Type  I_Slip_Num
>   Marina_Slip.Slip_Num%Type  I_Rental_Fee   Marina_Slip.Rental_Fee%Type 
>   I_Boat_Name    Marina_Slip.Boat_Name%Type  I_Owner_Num
>   Marina_Slip.Owner_Num%Type;
>
> Begin  Select Marina_Num, Slip_Num, Rental_Fee, Boat_Name, Owner_Num 
>   Into I_Marina_Num, I_Slip_Num, I_Rental_Fee, I_Boat_Name, I_Owner_Num 
>   from Marina_Slip  Where Length = ??

That last part I'm still missing, as I'm have no specific value for Length to restrict my output. and also cannot come up with a DBMS output.

Comment: Have a look at this link [Mysql stored procedure parameters](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable in paranthesis is a parameter. Yo can use it in your where clause.
For example :

```
(myLenght INT)

where length = myLength
```

You may define more than one parameters separated by a comma sign `,`

See also: [Mysql stored procedure parameters](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)